# jQuery ui input prepend

Tags: jquery, user-interface, input

Is there a jquery plugin that uses UI to prepend or append static text to an input field, like so:
[image]

I know twitters bootstrap can do it, but I can't seem to find anything like it for jquery ui.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you can probably fake it using a div, with a borderless input, and a few in-line blocks of span (with a gray background) floaing left.

That is if I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing it that way, still would have prefered it with a jquery ui style option though